# React Materials UI - How can I close two dialogs at the same time

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a nested popup dialog component(From materials UI) which including two dialogs, each of them maintains state 'open', this state is used to determine if the dislog window is open. Is it possible to close both when I close the top dialog down, which needs to set both states to 'false'

Compoent Structure:

```
-Dialog1
 -Dialog2
```

State for them:

```
Dialog1: { open: true }
Dialog2: { open: true }
```

Can I set the state of Dialog1 as well when I change the state of Dialog2? Can anyone help?[image]

Comment: yes, it's possible. you need to change the state of both dialogs when the top one is about to close. please provide some code so I can help further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to achieve this but it depends on how you'd want to implement it or makes sense.

As there is no specific code provided, will provide some ways you can consider.

1. [Liffing state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).
2. Notify parent via callback
3. Context API

### 1. Lifting state up

You can simply move the states for dialog 1 & 2 to the parent component.

```
function Parent() {
  const [dialogStates, setDialogStates] = useState({
    isDialog1Open: false,
    isDialog2Open: false
  });

  ...
}
```

### 2. Notify parent via callback

You can provide a function to be called when child dialog is called.

Check out the sorta-pseudo code like snippet below.

```
function ParentDialog() {
  const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isChildDialogOpen, setIsChildDialogOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Dialog isOpen={isDialogOpen}>
      <ChildDialog onCancel={() => setIsDialogOpen(false)} />
    </Dialog>
  );
}

function ChildDialog({ onCancel }) {
  return <Dialog onCancelClick={onCancel}>...</Dialog>;
}
```

### 3. Context API

You can notify the parent from children to close using a dispatch.

This is one of the ways to implement it.
(And you can make the context API more sharable using [this post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively)).

```
const DialogStateContext = createContext();
const DialogActionContext = createContext();

function dialogReducer(state, action) {
  ... toggle dialog states here...
}

function DialogContainer({children}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dialogReducer, initialState)

  return (
    <DialogStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <DialogActionContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
       {children}
      </DialogActionContext.Provider>
    </DialogStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

function ParentDialog() {
  const state = useContext(DialogStateContext)

  return (
    <Dialog isOpen={state.isParentDialogOpen}>
      <ChildDialog onCancel={() => setIsDialogOpen(false)} />
    </Dialog>
  );
}

function ChildDialog({ onCancel }) {
  const dispatch = useContext(DialogActionContext)
  return <Dialog onCancelClick={() => dispatch({type: 'close parent dialog'})}>...</Dialog>;
}
```

Comment: Does parent component means the component to wrap these two dialogs?

Comment: @HungryBird Yes. Or else you can simply life the state of `child` dialog's open/close state to the parent dialog.